# Water mask from NDVI from 8 day NDVI in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

With the following code, I am trying to make a water mask from the Landsat 8's LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI dataset.

The bit I am stuck on is how to create an if statement that will change the values of the pixels to 1 if greater than 0 and to -1 if less than zero.

The goal is to have the water in blue and everything is in white, with the ability to investigate the rivers visual size and shape at times of interest.

I have tried using ee.Algorithm.If but I am missing something in the syntax or it is not the best method?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/deab597e9a22de0bdde2876c1ab9f1ff

[image: Water]

```
//Water NDVI Mask
var NDVI_dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI')
                  .filterDate('2016-10-01', '2016-10-15')
                                    ;
var NDVI_Visualisation = NDVI_dataset.select('NDVI');

var water = ee.Algorithms.If(NDVI_Visualisation.set(>=0, 1, -1));

//Display the NDVI
Map.addLayer(NDVI_Visualisation,
 {bands: 'NDVI', min: -1, max: 1, gamma: 1.6, opacity: 1,},
 'NDVI Visualisation', false);

 var VIS_WATER_MASK = {
  min: -1,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['blue', 'white']
};



Map.addLayer({
  eeObject: NDVI_Visualisation,
  visParams: VIS_WATER_MASK,
  name: 'Water',
  shown: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation you can find that .set is used to write image metadata. So although your logic makes sense, you need a different functionality.

You could use the if-statement, if you truly want to have -1 as a outcome value. When your purpose is to isolate waterpixels you could also use the boolean logic directly:

```
var water = NDVI_Visualisation.first().lt(0)
Map.addLayer(water)
Map.addLayer(water.selfMask(), {palette: ['red']})
```

Oh and I used the .first statement to make a Image from your NDVI collection (selecting the first image). You could consider mapping over an entire image collection if you want to do this for multiple images in a collection.